# Python-Change another user's password

Tags: python, ubuntu, sudo

So, using Python and os.system, how would I change another user's password?
I know using the command passwd doesn't work. 
I was able (I think) to create a user with a password, using -p, but I do not know how to change a user's password through script.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is likely to use subprocesses.  Anything you can you on the shell you can put into a subprocess call.  This isn't ideal for all admin tasks, but considering the task is not portable I don't know a suitable module.

This will run the "passwd test" command just like from the shell and feed in the password string for the two password prompts.  The output is split into standard output and standard error by communicate().

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
username = 'test'
password = 'qZt53h9b'
proc=Popen(['passwd', username],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
proc.stdin.write(password + '\n')
proc.stdin.write(password)
proc.stdin.flush()
stdout,stderr = proc.communicate()
print(stdout)
print(stderr)
```

Don't forget you will get a permissions error trying to change another user's password when not root or as a sudoer.